# Eigenvalues of the sum of a stochastic matrix and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $D$ be a real diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)$ with $a_1\le a_2\le\ldots\le a_n$. Assume that at least one of the $a_i$ is positive. Let $P$ be an irreducible, real, row-stochastic matrix (all entries between 0 and 1, the sum of the elements of every row is 1), with all its eigenvalues real. Let $k>0$ be a real number. I wish to prove that $D+kP$ has a positive eigenvalue. Do you think this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Yes, it's true. Actually, the assumptions that $P$ is irreducible and row-stochastic can be removed. All we need is only that $P$ is (entrywise) nonnegative.

Since $P$ is nonnegative, so is $D-a_1I+kP$. By [Perron-Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), the spectral radius $\rho(D-a_1I+kP)$ is an eigenvalue of $D-a_1I+kP$. Thus $\lambda=a_1+\rho(D-a_1I+kP)$ is a real eigenvalue of $D+kP$. It remains to show that $\lambda>0$.

As $D-a_1I+kP$ is entrywise bounded below by the nonnegative matrix $D-a_1I$, we see that $(D-a_1I+kP)^m$ is entrywise bounded below by $(D-a_1I)^m$ for every positive integer $m$. By using [Gelfand's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Theorem_.28Gelfand.27s_formula.2C_1941.29) with [Frobenius norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm), it follows that $\rho(D-a_1I+kP)\ge\rho(D-a_1I)=a_n-a_1$. Therefore $\lambda=a_1+\rho(D+kP-a_1I)\ge a_n>0$.

Comment: A clever and very elegant answer. Thank you!

Comment: Very beautiful and elaborated answer.

Comment: @user67490 You can also thank user1551 by voting up his answer.

Comment: @user67692 Beautiful enough to warrant an upvote, don't you think?